# copying the old table - trigger in sql\plpgsql

Tags: postgresql, triggers, plpgsql

i have a trigger for a certain table in my database,

```
CREATE TRIGGER trig_trig
AFTER DELETE OR UPDATE OR INSERT ON A 
FOR EACH ROW
EXECUTE PROCEDURE trig_func();
```

anyway.. i want to create a copy of the old table, and then run some tests on the difference between the 2.

to copy a table is easy , simply i do :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION trig_func() RETURNS TRIGGER AS $$
BEGIN

CREATE TABLE temp as(SELECT * FROM A);
DROP TABLE temp;
return new; 
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

but i want to get the version before and after the change. this will simply give me one of them
i tried:

```
CREATE TABLE temp as(SELECT * FROM OLD.A);
```

or

```
CREATE TABLE temp as(SELECT * FROM NEW.A);
```

but i just get an error.

does anyone know how to do it?

thanx.
matt

Comment: This is nothing to do with "SQL Server" from Microsoft at all... tags changed to reflect the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`OLD` and `NEW` are pseudo-records. Rows, not tables, you can't select *from* them.

I can hard suggest how to do **it**, because it is not clear what exactly your intention is. Maybe you want to create one copy `BEFORE` the operation and one `AFTER`? In separate triggers?

Comment: hey, thanx for the response..
that is exactly what i want.
i want to have the copy of the table before it was changed, and then compare it to the new copy.
what do you mean by seperate trigers?

Comment: you have a trigger `AFTER DELETE...` — what I mean is creating another trigger with `BEFORE`. I hope your table isn't too big :)